# One input file to multiple output files

Tags: python

I found some helpful stuff on this site but my input file is different from the examples already posted and I cannot make the leap in an efficient manner.

My input file looks like this:

```
sample_dude data1 data2 data3 data4
sample_lady data5 data6 data7 data8
sample_dude data9 data10 data11 data12
sample_child data13 data14 data15 data16
```

I want to create a separate file for each sample with all the data columns.  For example, one file would be called sample_dude.txt and look like this:

```
data1 data2 data3 data4
data9 data10 data11 data12
```

There is an unknown number of samples but always just four data columns.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

PS: I'm trying to do this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example like this:

```
with open('input.txt') as input:
    for line in input:
        name, data = line.split(' ', 1)

        with open('{0}.txt'.format(name), 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by opening the file and looping through each line. I won't write the code for you, but here is an algorithm.

```
# Open the input file
# Loop through each line of the file
    # Split the line into the file name and the data
    # Open the file name and append the data to the end
```

You could also save the data for all files before opening them for writing. This would be faster if you have lots of files with multiple lines.

Comment: +1 for not writing the code; I on the other hand couldn’t resist.

Comment: I can do each thing in this list but the last part "Open the file name and append the data to the end".  I can open the input file, split each line into parts, and then write those parts to A file but I don't know how to write out multiple files (or open multiple files I haven't created it).

Comment: @user1265669: The name of each output file will correspond to the first item read on each line -- so open a file with a name based on that. If you want to add data to the end, open it in append mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? Split map all the filenames to a list of columns, create and write lines out to each file.

```
with open('someFile.txt') as f:
  out = {}
  for line in f:
    key, data = line.split(' ', 1)        
    if not key in out.keys():
      out[key] = []
    out[key].append(data)

for k, v in out.items():
  with open(k+'.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(v)
```